# Withdrawal of a research article from the journal

Tags: publications

How to withdraw a submitted (but not under review) manuscript from a journal? The reason being it has taken a lot of time (around 5 months) and has not gone under review process as of yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to withdraw an under review manuscript from a journal when you decide you want to submit to another journal with a higher impact factor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90898/how-to-withdraw-an-under-review-manuscript-from-a-journal-when-you-decide-you-wa)

Answer (score 4):

You email the journal/editor. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

The precise answer depends on the publisher. Usually if you log into the website where you can view your submission, there is also an option to withdraw. Presumably since you are able to check that it is not yet under review the journal in question is using this sort of system. If you can't find an option to withdraw, there should at least be an option to send a message to the handling editor, where you can request this.